# How would you format this URL, it is giving me "Illegal character in path at index 70"?

Tags: android, url, format, illegal-characters

I'm getting "Illegal character in path at index 70". And the final URL on debugging is coming like:

```
http://dev.example.com/Service/MyService.svc/CheckEmail/{0}
```

But I want the URL to be like:

```
http://dev.example.com/Service/MyService.svc/CheckEmail/rashid
```

I'm little new in Android, how can I achieve my desired result? Any help with explanation will be appreciated.

Below is the code:

```
String baseUrl = "http://dev.example.com/Service/MyService.svc/";
String url = String.format("CheckEmail/{0}", name);
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(baseUrl + url);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this way may help you

```
String url = String.format("CheckEmail/%s", name);
```

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't use `{}` syntax for String.format. You confused it with a C# language. Java uses printf-like %-syntax for arguments.
Se [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) for details. In your case you should use

```
String url = String.format("CheckEmail/%s", name);
```

Comment: Thanks nnesterov, it worked. You are right you caught me mixing c# with java. Thanks for explaining.